# Guess Game Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Criei um código em Python para apresentar um jogo da advinhação, de números entre 1 e 100. Queria implementar esse jogo em uma interface gráfica, usando o módulo Tkinter. Tive uma ideia, criei um código usando o tkinter, mas depois disso travei. Minha dúvida é, como "unir" os dois códigos que foram criados em um só, para criar essa interface gráfica.

Essa parte é que eu usei para criar a caixa com a apresentação do jogo e o botão para executar usando o Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

i = Tk()

i.title('Guess Game')
i.geometry("400x200")

texto = Label(i, text = "Bem-vindo ao Guess Game")
texto.pack()

texto = Label(i, text = "Você tem 10 chances de acertar o número que eu estou pensando.")
texto.pack()
texto = Label(i, text = "Trata-se de um valor entre 1 e 100. Então, vamos lá!")
texto.pack()

form = Entry(i, width=3)
form.pack()

b = Button(i, text ="Executar", fg= "green")
b.pack()

i.mainloop()
```

Já essa parte é a do código do Jogo em sí, criado anteriormente.

```
import random

n = random.randrange(1, 101)
nrepete = []
estado1 = 7  # início
estado2 = 7


def Submeter(tentativa):

    global estado2

    if abs(n - palpite) == 1:
        estado2 = 6  # fervendo
    if abs(n - palpite) == 2 or abs(n - palpite) == 3:
        estado2 = 5  # muito quente
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 4 and abs(n - palpite) <= 6:
        estado2 = 4  # quente
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 7 and abs(n - palpite) <= 9:
        estado2 = 3  # morno
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 10 and abs(n - palpite) <= 15:
        estado2 = 2  # frio
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 16 and abs(n - palpite) <= 25:
        estado2 = 1  # muito frio
    if abs(n - palpite) >= 26:
        estado2 = 0  # congelando


def FornecerPista():
    if estado1 == 7:
        if estado2 == 0:
            print('Está congelando!')
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Está muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Está frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Está morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Está quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Está muito quente!')
        if estado2 == 6:
            print('Está fervendo!')
    if estado1 - estado2 == 0:
        if estado2 == 0:
            print('Seu palpite continua congelando!')
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Seu palpite continua muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Seu palpite continua frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Seu palpite continua morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Seu palpite continua quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Seu palpite continua muito quente!')
        if estado2 == 6:
            print('Seu palpite continua fervendo!')
    if estado1 - estado2 > 0:
        if estado2 == 0:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está congelando!')
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esfriada e agora está muito quente!')
    if estado1 - estado2 < 0:
        if estado2 == 1:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está muito frio!')
        if estado2 == 2:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está frio!')
        if estado2 == 3:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está morno!')
        if estado2 == 4:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está quente!')
        if estado2 == 5:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está muito quente!')
        if estado2 == 6:
            print('Ops, seu palpite deu uma esquentada e agora está fervendo!')


for tentativa in range(1, 11):
    while True:
        try:
            palpite = input('Tentativa' + str(tentativa) + ':')
            palpite = int(palpite)
            nrepete.append(palpite)
            if (palpite < 1) or (palpite > 100):
                raise ValueError
            if nrepete.count(palpite) >= 2:
                raise NameError
            else:
                break
        except NameError:
            print('Esse valor já foi testado! Tente de novo.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Valor inválido! Tente de novo.')

    if palpite == n:
        print('\nParabéns !')
        print('\nVocê acertou o número', n, 'após', tentativa, 'tentativa(s)!')
        break
    if tentativa == 1:
        SetStatus(tentativa)
    if tentativa > 1:
        estado1 = estado2
        SetStatus(tentativa)
    FornecerPista()

    if tentativa == 10 and palpite != n:
        print('\nLamento, mas após', tentativa, 'tentativas')
        print('Você não conseguiu acertar o número', n, 'que eu estava pensando!')
```

Comment: Como faria isso?

Comment: Eu fiz isso, entretanto quando boto o pra rodar ele só executa o segundo bloco, nada da parte gráfica.

Comment: Sua lógica implementada na criação da janela do `Tkinter` é boa mas a mesma não fará nada pois ela não recebe nenhum dado externo.

Comment: Pois é, essa que era a minha pergunta. Consegui criar a janela, mas não consegui usar o segundo bloco na mesma.

Comment: No seu segundo arquivo você parece ter feito o script para console, ele não está se comunicando com o `Tkinter`. O `Tkinter` funciona basicamente da seguinte forma: Você defini um widget seja uma janela, botão ou o que seja, e define um comando que o mesmo executará caso aja interação com o usuário um exemplo seria `button = tk.Button(text='Clique aqui', command=<função_que_será_executada>)`. Para mais leia https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você precisa fazer os códigos interagirem.
Basicamente precisa colocar todo o jogo para rolar após apertar o botão.

Inclua isso:

```
def codigo_do_jogo():
    #Aqui você coloca praticamente todo o código do jogo. 

b = Button(i, text ="Executar", command= codigo_do_jogo, fg= "green")#Adiciona o comando no botão.
b.pack()
```

Outra coisa importante é o campo entrada,

```
form = Entry(i, width=3)
form.pack()
```

Para que ele pegue o valor que a pessoa digitou use o método `.get()`:

```
form.get()

#Por exemplo, se fizer assim será printado o que foi digitado pelo usuário:
print(form.get())
```

Para finalizar, dessa forma você pode devolver valores à interface, provavelmente devem existir formas mais "certas" de fazer isso:

```
def surgir_resultado(resultado):
    texto = Label(i, text = resultado)
    texto.pack()
```

Assim vai surgir no pai `i` o seu texto, quando `surgir_resultado(resultado)` for chamado. Lembrando que ele pode ser chamado por um comando do botão.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Para dar uma luz nesse código posso dizer que é bom ter os dois códigos de interface e de programa interno feitos separados. Pude constatar nos meus estudos que primeiramente deve-se criar a interface gráfica e as validações e aos poucos ir juntado a outra parte do programa. Tudo tem que ter uma ordem, por exemplo: 1º Bolar uma pergunta ou algoritmo do que se pretende fazer. 2º Os widgets e layouts já definidos e planejado. 3º programa interno em si. Fiz um programa baseado no seu que ficou um pouco diferente. Difícil é seguir as mesmas ideias. Também tentei tirar a máximo as exceções. Criei referência que definem a temperatura que são: Fervendo, muito quente, quente, morno, frio, muito frio e Congelando. A temperatura se dá fazendo esse calculo: (computador**-**palpites = referência). Verifique a interface executada com os dados no console para tirar as suas conclusões.

```
from tkinter import *

from random import *

from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo  

i = Tk()

i.title('Guess Game')

i.geometry("400x200")

texto3 = Label(i, text = ">>> Último valor digitado -texto3- <<<", relief=RAISED)

texto3.pack()

palpite = Entry(i, width=3)

palpite.focus()

palpite.pack()

computador = randint(1, 100)

print('computador sorteou: ', computador)

don=0

def botao():

    palpites = palpite.get()

    polpa = palpites[:]

    if polpa == '':

        showinfo(title="Mensagem", message="*** Campo vazio ***")

    elif not polpa.isnumeric():

        showinfo(title="Mensagem", message="*** Digite apenas numeros ***")

        palpite.delete(0, 'end')

    elif int(polpa) <= 0 or int(polpa) >= 101:

        showinfo(title="Mensagem", message="*** Digite entre 1 e 100 ***")

        palpite.delete(0, 'end') # limpa a caixa de entrada

    else:

        global computador

        palpites = str(palpite.get())

        print('palpites: ', palpites)

        texto3['text'] = palpites  # último valor digitado

        cont = 0

        while cont <= 10:

            global don

            if int(palpites) == int(computador):

                texto1['text'] = '<Congratulações> você ACERTOU !!!'

                palpite.delete(0, 'end')

                b['state'] = DISABLED

                texto1.configure(bg='green', fg='yellow')

                palpite['state'] = DISABLED

                texto2['text'] = 'fim do jogo'

                break

            elif int(palpites) != int(computador):

                referencia = int(computador) - int(palpites)

                print('=== Valor de referência: ', referencia)

                if (referencia >= 1 and referencia <= 10):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Fervendo => é mais'

                elif (referencia >= -10 and referencia <= -1):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Fervendo => é menos'

                elif (referencia >= 11 and referencia <= 20):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Está muito quente = > é mais'

                elif (referencia >= -20 and referencia <= -11):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Está muito quente => é menos'

                elif (referencia >= 21 and referencia <= 30):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Quente => é mais'

                elif (referencia >= -30 and referencia <= -21):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Quente => é menos'

                elif (referencia >= 31 and referencia <= 40):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Está morno => é mais'

                elif (referencia >= -40 and referencia <= -31):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Está morno => é menos'

                elif (referencia >= 41 and referencia <= 50):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Frio => é mais'

                elif (referencia >= -50 and referencia <= -41):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Frio => é menos'

                elif (referencia >= 51 and referencia <= 60):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Muito frio => é mais'

                elif (referencia >= -60 and referencia <= -51):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Muito frio => é menos'

                elif (referencia >= 61):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Está congelando => é mais'

                elif (referencia <= -61):

                    texto2['text'] = 'Está congelando => é menos'

                else:

                    texto2['text'] = 'algo deu errado'

                texto1['text'] = 'ERROU'

                cont += 1

                don += cont

                print('>> Cont => Número de tentativas: ', don)

                palpite.delete(0, 'end')

                if don == 10:

                    b['state'] = DISABLED

                    palpite['state'] = DISABLED

                    texto1.configure(bg='red', fg='yellow')

                    texto2['text'] = 'fim do jogo'

                    texto1['text'] = 'Que pena! ** ERRASTE ** totas a tentativas'

                break

        print('status: ', texto1['text'])

        print('-----------------------------------')

texto = Label(i, text = "Bem-vindo ao jogo")

texto.pack()

texto = Label(i, text = "Você tem 10 chances de acertar o número que eu estou pensando.")

texto.pack()

texto = Label(i, text = "Trata-se de um valor entre 1 e 100. Então, vamos lá!")

texto.pack()

texto1 = Label(i, text = ">>>  <<<", relief=RAISED)

texto1.pack()

texto2 = Label(i, text = ">>> Temperatura <<<", relief=RAISED)

texto2.pack()


b = Button(i, text ="Executar", fg= "green", command=botao)

b.pack()

i.mainloop()
```